# What is story of Ati Varadar Swamy?

Tags: vishnu, history, temple

The main deity (moolavar) of Ati Vardar Swamy of Swamy Varadaraja Perumal is immersed in nearby pushkarini . It is taken out for public worship every 40 years, next time this is going to happen in 2019 for 48 days. I want to know the story of Ati Varadar moolavar, why is it kept underwater.

Comment: @PrasannaR how much do you know about temple agamas?  Are you aware that the moolavar is hampered by islamic psychopaths that is why it is not worshipped.

Comment: @PrasannaR you should know that a vigraha that is damaged or hampered cannot be worshipped either it has to be repaired using agama techniques or if beyond repair should be replaced in case of atthi vardar he manifested from agni of the yagna performed by bramha so he is irreplaceable... Also there is one more story saying that due to his manifestation from fire he asked devotees to keep him in water Period.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar hi, I am fine... Yeah will catch up.

Comment: @Yogi so if its irreplaceable than have it for public view why hide.. by the story is true than keep Athi varadar in glass container in water in public view daily change the water give it as prasad to devotees why hide?

Comment: @PrasannaR if they wanted to hide they wouldnt have kept him in public for 48 days. The glass container thing is a good solution but might not be feasible with agama. Why are you so desperate to prove that what vaishnavas are doing is wrong?

Comment: @PrasannaR no one told the public to come. And have darshanam at the first place last coming of athi vardar was not so crowded. The kainkaryakartas of vardar swamy temple have more knowledge of agamas then you and me so they for sure know what is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97147/discussion-between-prasanna-r-and-yogi).